# Execution of Rabbit message listener failed

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I`ve tried the course on udemy and there was a chapter - Rabbit Listener With Spring Boot

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RabbitMQConsumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "Mobile")
    public void getMessage(Person p){

        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```

This is the error stack

```
ter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:258) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted

2024-02-12T14:46:30.514+02:00  WARN 5676 --- [ntContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:158) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1682) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1592) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1528) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1377) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1279) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to deserialize unauthorized class com.example.demo.Person; add allowed class name patterns to the message converter or, if you trust the message originator, set environment variable 'SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL' or system property 'spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all' to true
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.checkAllowedList(SerializationUtils.java:164) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AllowedListDeserializingMessageConverter.checkAllowedList(AllowedListDeserializingMessageConverter.java:61) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter$1.resolveClass(SimpleMessageConverter.java:151) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2034) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1898) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1733) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:102) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:83) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:385) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-amqp-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:258) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I should get the message with the name of the person.

Comment: Please view my response to this issue in the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064593/8185956